# Apache FOP, how to set background color of PDF generated with PDFTranscoder

Tags: java, svg, apache-fop

I need to convert an SVG to PDF using apache FOP. I have a solution that is basically working.
The problem, however, is that I am not able to set the background color of the PDF.
Currently, I have tried setting the background color in the style of the root SVG element. The SVG is displayed correctly in SVG viewers, but when converted to PDF, the background color is missing. So I assume the SVG / PDF transcoders do not have support for this.

What I am trying now is to set the background color in the configuration of the PDFTranscoder.
But unfortunalty, this does not seem possible either. The PDFTranscoder.KEY_BACKGROUND_COLOR key that is mentioned in the class documentation here (https://www.cs.helsinki.fi/group/xmltools/formatters/fop/fop-0.93/javadocs/org/apache/fop/svg/PDFTranscoder.html)  does not seem to exist:

```
    PDFTranscoder pdf = new PDFTranscoder();
    pdf.addTranscodingHint(SVGAbstractTranscoder.KEY_WIDTH, width);
    pdf.addTranscodingHint(SVGAbstractTranscoder.KEY_HEIGHT, height);
    pdf.addTranscodingHint(PDFTranscoder.KEY_DEVICE_RESOLUTION, resolution);
    pdf.addTranscodingHint(PDFTranscoder.KEY_BACKGROUND_COLOR, backgroundColor);
```

Comment: Why not put a rect element the size of the viewport as the first element in the SVG with the colour you want as the background?

Comment: are you using the latest 2.1 version of FOP? could batik do the pdf conversion itself w/o FOP?

Comment: yes,  I am using the 2.1 version